# Getting rid of an auto generated unnamed column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataset that has some missing values in csv format and that it does not have column names. In this dataset there are two columns that I want to extract first before doing an imputation process. The first one is the ID column and the second one is a column that gives me the number of a class. After the imputation process I want to store the dataframe into a csv file.

So far the code that I have is the following:

```
    colNames=['id', 'clump','unif_c','unif_c_s','marg', 'single_epith','bare','bland','normal','mitoses','class']
    data=pd.read_csv("breast-cancer-wisconsin.data",names=colNames)
    colN=['clump','unif_c','unif_c_s','marg', 'single_epith','bare','bland','normal','mitoses',]
    y=data["class"]
    data=data.drop(["id","class"],axis="columns")
    data.replace('?',np.nan,inplace=True)
    imp=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.NaN,strategy='mean')
    data=pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(data[colN]),columns=data.columns)
    data["class"]=y
    data.to_csv("generatedFile.csv",index="False")
```

The problem that I have is that the generated csv file instead of being like this:

[image]

It generates me an unnamed column like this:

[image]

I have tried everything and I don't know why this column is appearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the last line -

```
data.to_csv("generatedFile.csv",index=False)
```

**Explanation**

`False` has to be passed as a `bool` without the quotes.

Comment: Good eye. `"False"` is of course `True`.

Answer (score 0):

This unamed column is the index, pandas should have index column.
you can set index to one of your columns instead, for exampe:

```
data=data.set_index('id')
```

Comment: OP tries to suppress the index with `index="False"` (and that is the bug). Simply redefining the index won't work, especially since "id" has been dropped.

Comment: offcourse, if "id" will be used, it will not be dropped, Thanks.